# Phalcon\Mvc\Model findBy*** static methods

Tags: php, phalcon

Today i discovered that my model object has methods like findBy{property}. (i am using phalcon 0.9.0)

For example, i have model Language with id, code, name properties.
And for each i can call methods like `Language::findByCode('en');` or  `Language::findByName('English');`

this is unbelieveable fantastic. can i use this in my project (it is big enough, so i don't want to rewrite the code later)? i mean will those static methods appear in the future?

And is there any docs about those methods? I was unable to find such docs about this :((

Answer (score 0):

This functionality has been introduced in 0.9.0 which is still in Beta stage.

The documents for 0.9.0 can be found [here](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/0.9.0/index.html). However since 0.9.0 is not marked as stable yet, there is work to be done for the relevant docs version.